# Building a query to search for multiple attributes

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I am very new to coding, especially with Symfony. But now my teacher has given me a task to create a query to search within 2 attributes. I have started writing the query, but there is still a lot lacking. I am wondering if someone can help, or send a link to help me finish it.

I need to make a search option which looks up into Artikelnummer and Omschrijving.

```
/**
* @Route("/artikel/zoek", name="zoekartikel")
*/
Public function zoek(Request $request){
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $query = $em->createQuery(
       'SELECT a
       FROM AppBundle:Artikel a
       WHERE a.artikelnummer = input AND a.omschrijving LIKE input2'
   );
   $artikelen = $query->getResult();
   return new Response($this->render('search.html.twig',
   array('artikelen' => $artikelen)));

}
```

Comment: if `input` and `input2` are just strings use it like this `WHERE a.artikelnummer = 'input' AND a.omschrijving LIKE 'input2'` and also replace the first `a` after `SELECT` with the character `*`.

Comment: I have problems defining the strings here. So they are not yet defined

Comment: Okay. Try with some hard coded strings at first so you can see if the query is working after that you can input strings accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to instantiate Result Mapping

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
```

Then

```
$query = $em-> createNativeQuery(
       'SELECT a
       FROM AppBundle:Artikel a
       WHERE a.artikelnummer = ? AND a.omschrijving LIKE ?', 
       $rsm
   );

$query->setParameter(1, 'input1'); // or var
$query->setParameter(2, 'input2'); // or var
$artikelen = $query->getResult();
return new Response($this->render('search.html.twig',
   array('artikelen' => $artikelen)));
```

More docs here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Comment: Why would you use a NativeQuery and ResultSetMapping for this task when it can justr as easily be accomplished (actually, identically) with DQL and without the ResultSetMapping?